# Image method for room impulse response simulation

Tags: acoustics, reflection, method-of-images

I am following [this paper](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1121/1.382599?casa_token=9EaT9EPIRocAAAAA:wSzS6RoldmO0tOHgiU6I-EwFPqGUEcnfRL8iR8aTGcZHZFeEMzn3vaNHpJ-SyQmsF7BPPYGpFPw) on simulating a room impulse response (RIR). The wave of a single frequency $\omega$ point sound source in location $X$ as it is viewed by a microphone located at $X'$ is:
$$P(\omega,X,X')=\frac{e^{i\omega(\frac{R}{C}-t)}}{4\pi R}$$
Where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, $R=|X-X'|$ and $C$ is the speed of sound in the volume.

I am at a loss at the formulation part when transitioning between equations (3) and (5). I understand the track of imaging the source location with the 2d case. As presented in the attached image, the source could be mirrored (spatially) to the other side of the wall as a second source to account for the wall's reflection.

[image]

This for the 2d case of a rigid wall depicts from above. and explains the $R_-, R_+$ locations. Hence, accounting for a simple reflection we get:
$$P(\omega,X,X')=\left[\frac{e^{i\omega\frac{R_+}{C}}}{4\pi R_+}+\frac{e^{i\omega\frac{R_-}{C}}}{4\pi R_-}\right]e^{-i\omega t} $$
However, in the 3d scenario, we have multiple (continuous) such beams along the hight of the wall. Also, the reflection of other walls (rectangular room) is present. They scale up to the equation:
$$P(\omega,X,X')=\sum_{p=1}^8\sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{i\omega|R_p+R_r|}}{4\pi|R_p+R_r|}e^{-i\omega t}$$

Appendix A is supposed to clear the reasoning behind that transition. I am very rusty when we get to solving the waves equation, hence, that is where I completely lost it. I see an equation $\bigtriangledown^2P[\frac{\omega}{C},X,X']+\frac{\omega^2}{C^2}P[\frac{\omega}{C},X,X']=\delta[X-X']$ (is it an ODE?). I do not know what they are looking for (I am guessing a $P(\omega, X, X')$ which will sustain the equation?). What is up with the exponential expansion of cosine and why only to the 8th degree? Can anyone elaborate on the solution at the elementary level for both the math and the intuition?

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked paper is not freely available and we cannot get our eyes on it. This means we cannot really follow your problem and provide insight. You'd have to copy all relevant information from the paper to the post. The last equation you provide seems to be the inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation which in a sense is the steady-state wave equation in the frequency domain. Most probably, the article is interested in solving/approximating this equation, which is rather common in acoustics (and virtual acoustics) problems.